# Convert SWF file to FLV with FFMPEG & getting error "could not find codec parameters"

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, flv

Hi I am trying to convert SWF file to FLV, but i am getting same eror

```
C:\Users\Administrator>C:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe -i C:/xampplite/htdocs/ffmpeg/1.swf \
 C:/xampplite/htdocs/ffmpeg/file1.flv 

FFmpeg version SVN-r16573, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. 
configuration: --extra-cflags=-fno-common --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads 
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora 
--enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 
--enable-libschroedinger --enable-avisynth --enable-swscale --enable-gpl 
  libavutil 49.12. 0 / 49.12. 0 
  libavcodec 52.10. 0 / 52.10. 0 
  libavformat 52.23. 1 / 52.23. 1 
  libavdevice 52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0 
  libswscale 0. 6. 1 / 0. 6. 1 
built on Jan 13 2009 02:57:09, gcc: 4.2.4 
C:/xampplite/htdocs/ffmpeg/1.swf: could not find codec parameters
```

Please solve this problem, what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

SWF isn't a media container like MP4 or AVI. It has lot's of things more like vector data for graphics, ActionScript code, etc. It can also embed FLV files as resources.

So, there is no point trying to directly convert a SWF to FLV using FFMPEG. You can try to extract it's resources by using a tool, like [SWF Extractor](http://www.globfx.com/products/swfre/), to get the FLV file and then use FFMPEG to convert it to another format, like AVI or MP4.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. Are you *really* sure the SWF has an embedded FLV in it?
2. Decompile the SWF into its individual components.  Maybe it is too complex, or has multiple FLVs in it, or some other metadata like issue